# How to Combine Multiple Tables to Get output in SQL (PHP MyAdmin)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to get the below result with 3 tables in SQL and PHPmyAdmin from the last 2 days, can someone please help to reach the output? I appreciate your support in advance.

i am using this query but not able to achive the output.

```
SELECT calender.date, trade_details.client_code, 
        sum(trade_details.net_pnl) as trade_Value, 
        sum(kuber_reports.net_value) as kuber_Value
FROM calender
    LEFT JOIN trade_details ON calender.date = trade_details.trade_Date
    LEFT JOIN kuber_reports ON calender.date = kuber_reports.trans_Date
WHERE trade_details.client_code = 'GBN10001'
GROUP BY calender.date, trade_details.client_code;



Calendar Table

| ID       | date           |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 1        | 2022-12-13     |
| 2        | 2022-12-14     |
| 3        | 2022-12-15     |
| 4        | 2022-12-16     |
| 5        | 2022-12-17     |
| 6        | 2022-12-18     |


Kuber_reports Table

| ID       | trans_Date     | net_Value   | client_code      
| -------- | -------------- |-------------|-------------
| 1        | 2022-12-14     |  100        | GBN10001
| 2        | 2022-12-14     |  -50        | GBN10001
| 3        | 2022-12-14     |  100        | GBN10001
| 4        | 2022-12-15     |  500        | GBN10001
| 5        | 2022-12-16     |  1000       | GBN10001

trade_details Table

| ID       | trade_Date     | net_pnl   | client_code      
| -------- | -------------- |-------------|-------------
| 1        | 2022-12-14     |  100        | GBN10001
| 2        | 2022-12-14     |  -50        | GBN10001
| 3        | 2022-12-14     |  100        | GBN10001
| 4        | 2022-12-15     |  500        | GBN10001
| 5        | 2022-12-16     |  900        | GBN10001
```

Output Required

```
| ID       | Calender.date  | net_pnl     | net_value   | client_code | Difference    
| -------- | -------------- |-------------|-------------|-------------|------------
| 1        | 2022-12-14     |  150        |    150      | GBN10001    | 0
| 2        | 2022-12-15     |  500        |    500      | GBN10001    | 0
| 3        | 2022-12-16     |  900        |    1000     | GBN10001    |-100
```

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a tool written in PHP, MySQL is your DBMS

Answer (score 0):

Before joining the tables, you should aggregate the tables Kuber_reports and trade_details individually and then join the resultant tables.

```sql
select calender.date, trade_table.client_code,net_value,net_pnl,
differnce= net_pnl-net_value
from calender left join
(select trans_date,client_code, sum(net_value) as net_value
from Kuber_reports group by trans_date,client_code) Kuber_table
on calender.date=Kuber_table.trans_date
left join (select trade_Date, client_code, sum(net_pnl) as net_pnl
from trade_details group by trade_Date ,client_code) trade_table
on calender.date=trade_table.trade_Date
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/j1j7Wbmm)

To not display null values, it is better to add the following condition

```
where trade_table.client_code is not null
```